# How to use histogram as features when creating an image classifier using Tensor Flow?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, histogram

I'm still a student and I'm working on how to use histogram as features when creating an image classifier using Tensor Flow (I already used tensor flow for poets, but its inputs are raw images, now I want to use histograms as input). I watched its tutorial on how to do this using apples and oranges as features, but now I'm trying to use histograms of images (I've used opencv (python) to extract the histograms of my images).

I have 2 labels: image 1 and image 2. Each label has its own 60 images (image 1, has 60 images, image 2 has 60 images). And in each label, I have 60 histograms, and it's in the form of a 2D array.

```
 image1 = [[histogram1], [histogram2], ... [histogram60]]
 image2 = [[histogram1], [histogram2], ... [histogram60]]
```

In each histogram, I have 256 values,

```
 histogram1 = [0,0,0,0,123, 169, ...]
```

In my code right now, I'm having an error when I'm using these histograms as features since it's in the form of 3 dim-array, when it should only be <= 2. The way I wrote it is like this (based on TF's tutorial):

```
from sklearn import tree
hist = [ [[img1_histogram1], [img1_histogram2], ... [img1_histogram60]], [[img2_histogram1], [img2_histogram2], ... [img2_histogram60]] ]
labels = [1, 2] # 1 for image1, 2 image2
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(hist, labels)

print clf.predict([[img1_histogram1]])
```

Can anyone help me use histograms as features when creating image classifier using Tensor Flow? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way of representing an RGB histogram in a feature vector is to extract the relevant values from it.

So the histogram would be stored as: *redMean, greenMean, blueMean, redStdDev, greenStdDev, blueStdDev*

I've used this approach to represent color profiles of butterflies.